# what is the best way to store and access Date datatype in gremlin

Tags: gremlin

my data base stores Java Date,im passing milliseconds to search that date

```
g.V().has('employeeId','350d').collect({it.property('JoinedOn').value().getTime()})
==>1471866919024
```

but when i search for JoinedOn with the same milliseconds Value it shows null result

```
g.V().has('employeeId','350d').has('JoinedOn',new Date(1471866919024))
gremlin>
```

what is the best way to store and perform operations on Date objects in gremlin

Comment: Not clear on why that's not working for you... what is your graph backend? I just tried it successfully with TinkerGraph and TitanGraph https://gist.github.com/pluradj/6238d457b9a9cb67148759b5928322e7

Comment: im using titan and tinkerpop

Comment: Following is the way we created this property:`log.info("Creating property with key:JoinedOn.");
final PropertyKey JoinedOn = mgmt.makePropertyKey("JoinedOn").dataType(Date.class).make();
TitanManagement.IndexBuilder JoinedOnEMixedIndexBuilder = mgmt.buildIndex("byEdgeJoinedOnMixed", Edge.class).addKey(JoinedOn);
TitanGraphIndex JoinedOnEMixedIndex = JoinedOnEMixedIndexBuilder.buildMixedIndex(SEARCH_BACKEND);
log.info("Completed creating property with key:JoinedOn.");`

Comment: When we query using `g.V().has('employeeId','350d').has('JoinedOn',lt(new Date(1471866919024)))` it does return the vertex. Somehow the date inside the databse is less than the date. But when we query the date property itself, in milliseconds, it still shows the same value!

Comment: we are using titan11 branch and using cassandra as the backend and elasticsearch as the indexing engine.

Comment: Why not just store it as a long?

Comment: Actually we thought about this option, but we needed to perform some date operations. Say, I want to get all the employees joined in last 20 days to be a simple date operation.

Comment: converting from a long back into a Date is easy enough